# System.Linq.Dynamic library - need Count() example

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, count, linq-to-entities

I need most elegant solution for dynamic selecting/grouping/ordering via Linq2Entities (VB.NET/VS2012).

And I'm trying to use System.Linq.Dynamic library (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

This construсtion works fine

```
Dim testQuery= testDB.testTable.Select("New(Field1)").GroupBy("New(Field1)", "it")
```

But this one (found this example somewhere on blogs/SO) generates error:

```
Dim testQuery= testDB.testTable.Select("New(Field1, Count())").GroupBy("New(Field1, Count())", "it")
```

The error is "No applicable method 'Count' exists in type 'testTable'"

I know that this library was born dead, but official MS solution for dynamic queries with expressions-trees is kinda scary. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to retrieve the count of rows in `testTable` for each value of `Field1`, then I would have thought you want to firstly `GroupBy` `Field1`, then `Select` afterwards. So basically reverse the order of your `Select` and `GroupBy` and remove the `Count()` from the GroupBy.

Comment: I tried this construction:
    Dim testQuery= testDB.testTable.GroupBy("New(Field1)", "it").Select("New(Field1, Count())")

And got another error: "No property or field 'Field1' exists in type 'IGrouping`2'"

Comment: Ah yes, it might be called either "Key" or else "Key.Field1" in the grouping. When you group, you get back a list of objects that have a property of "Key", containing the field(s) you grouped by, and also can be enumerated themselves to get the records in that particular group.

Comment: Great! This one:

   `Dim testQuery= testDB.testTable.GroupBy("New(Field1)", "it").Select("New(Key.Field1, Count() as Total)")`

works fine! (BTW, "as Total" is also vital.) 

**Thak you so much!**